# How to extract the common condition check in a class

Tags: java

If I have a class, where all methods should evaluate only if a boolean attribute is `true`, what is the best way to define it in terms of best practices?

Is there a way to replace the recurring `isEnabled` check in all the methods by a single check? The current form works, I'm looking for a way to improve it to not have `isEnabled` checked in all the methods.

```
@Singleton
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

    EventPublisher eventPubilsher;
    boolean isEnabled;

    @Inject
    public SomeClass(final Decider decider, EventPublisher, eventPublisher) {
        this.isEnabled = decider.isSomethingEnabled();
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        if(isEnabled){
            eventPublisher.publishSomething1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        if(isEnabled){
            eventPublisher.publishSomething2();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        if(isEnabled){
            eventPublisher.publishSomething3();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO set enabled to publisher and always call `eventPublisher.publishSomething();` Less confuse

Comment: Are you having any issues with the current implementation?

Comment: get the `decider` out of the constructor and just pass a boolean instead

Comment: Can you either create a real publisher or a dummy/null publisher that does nothing, and decide which one to inject at construction time ?

Comment: Are the methods supposed to do anything when enabled is false? If not, why do you need an instance of this class? If it were null, then it's not "enabled", and you don't need to toggle its enabled state. However, it probably shouldn't be a singleton if doing that. At that point, this class is pointless as you could just use the instance of the publisher directly

Answer (score 1):

You can have implementation for enabled stuff, and one for disabled stuff. The disabled implementation won't do anything:

```
public class DisabledSomeClass implements SomeInterface {

  @Override
  public void method1() {
  }

  @Override
  public void method2() {
  }

  @Override
  public void method3() {
  }
}
```

Enabled one will publish stuff:

```
public class EnabledSomeClass implements SomeInterface {

  EventPublisher eventPublisher;

  public EnabledSomeClass(EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
    this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
  }

  @Override
  public void method1() {
    eventPublisher.publishSomething1();
  }

  @Override
  public void method2() {
    eventPublisher.publishSomething2();
  }

  @Override
  public void method3() {
    eventPublisher.publishSomething3();
  }
}
```

Then extract the logic, if functionality is enabled in new factory class - `SomeInterfaceFactory` (probably not the best name, but you get the idea), it will return the correct implementation, depending on whether something is enabled.

```
public class SomeInterfaceFactory {

  public static SomeInterface getInstance(Decider decider, EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
    if (decider.isSomethingEnabled()) {
      return new EnabledSomeClass(eventPublisher);
    } else {
      return new DisabledSomeClass();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Runnable interface can receive a lambda without args and run a lambda function with run() method. So, you can create a method inside your Decider class and receive a Runnable as a parameter, like:

```
class Decider{
    private boolean enabled;
    //...

    public void execute(Runnable runnable){
        if(enabled) runnable.run();
    }
}
```

And receive your Decider and do:

```
//...
EventPublisher eventPubilsher;
Decider decider;

@Inject
public SomeClass(final Decider decider, EventPublisher, eventPublisher) {
    this.decider = decider;
    this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
}
@Override
public void method1() {
    Decider.execute(() -> eventPublisher.publishSomething1());
}

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Singleton
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

    EventPublisher eventPubilsher;
    boolean isEnabled;

    @Inject
    public SomeClass(final Decider decider, EventPublisher, eventPublisher) {
        this.isEnabled = decider.isSomethingEnabled();
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        publish(ep->ep.publishSomething1());
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        publish(ep->ep.publishSomething2());
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        publish(ep->ep.publishSomething3());
    }

    private void publish(Consumer<EventPublisher> callback){
      if(isEnabled) callback.accept(eventPublished);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're locking the evaluation of the condition to the constructor.  If you want any flexibility, you should pull it out.

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
boolean isEnabled;

public SomeClass(EventPublisher, eventPublisher) {
     //
}

public void addDecide(boolean value){
    isEnabled = value;
}

boolean getEnabled(){
    return isEnabled;
}

@Override
public void method3() {
    if(getEnabled()){
        eventPublisher.publishSomething3();
    }
}
}
```

You can even go crazy and add a supplier:

```
public void addDecide(Supplier<Boolean> supplier){
    supplier = supplier;
}

boolean getEnabled(){
    return supplier.get();
}
```